# Instagram sandboxed app request with public_content scope returns empty result

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to pull media with certain tag. I've authorized and gotten back token with scope 'basic' and 'public_content'. However the following request gets back with status code 200 but empty data even though eg. tag 'london' has lot of content.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/london?access_token= [MY TOKEN]

Is this request malformed or is the Instagram API misbehaving?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In sandbox-mode, Instagram only returns the data associated with the sandbox users.

It's written down in the [docs, section API behaviour](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox):

> Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user.

[...]

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user.

If you create a "london" tag with your sandbox user, you should see it. Once your app has switched to live, you should see all public available "london" tags.

Your request is NOT malformed and the API behaves as described in the documentation.

Comment: I seem to have skimmed over that part too hastily, thanks. 

So I'm basically stuck as I wan't to try to incorporate public_content fetch via API on a student art project and there's no app as a end result. Also there's no possibility to try to submit the 'dummy' app I have as a client to review in order to go live and get sandbox restrictions lifted off. Bummer.

Comment: It's genuinely confusing. I took me a few days of work to figure it all out, so I wrote this quick article for other developers trying to quickly understand the [new Instagram API restrictions](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s).